# can not take data from stored procedure using python

Tags: python, sql

Hello i have faced issue. I believe you can fix it. I want to take data from sql in python. I used pyodbc library. There is stored procedure in sql. When i execute it at SQL it resulted 3 parts of results. Using pyodbc i run stored procedure then there is only head of columns of first part of result(empty data). How to take all part of result in python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide code implementation you have tried already and the errors if any.

Comment: Can you also add a short excerpt of your data (possibly with simulated data if you don't want to share your real data)?